# How to find the size of a templated type

Tags: c#, templates, sizeof

What is wrong with this?

```
int SizeOf<T> (T [] fred) { return fred.Length * sizeof(T); }
```

It does not compile.

My intention is to write a routine to write an array of integers, bytes or doubles to a binary file.  Something like

// Write array T[] data

```
void WriteToFile<T> (Filestream f, T[] data)
{
    int bufferSize = data.Length * sizeof(T);
    byte[] workBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, workBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
    f.Write(workBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
}
```

Is there any way to template this so that it would work for 2D arrays also (though it would be easy to adapt, if only sizeof(T) worked.

Comment: Please don't roll back our improvements to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is this:

> 'T' does not have a predefined size, therefore sizeof can only be used in an unsafe context (consider using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf)

The [documentation on the `sizeof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx) discusses this:

> For all other types, including structs, the sizeof operator can be used only in unsafe code blocks. Although you can use the Marshal.SizeOf method, the value returned by this method is not always the same as the value returned by sizeof. Marshal.SizeOf returns the size after the type has been marshaled, whereas sizeof returns the size as it has been allocated by the common language runtime, including any padding.

But you also [cannot use `sizeof` with any managed type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2estayf.aspx):

> Even when used with the unsafe keyword, taking the address of a managed object, getting the size of a managed object, or declaring a pointer to a managed type is not allowed. A managed type is:
>
> 1. any reference type
> 2. any struct that contains a reference type as a field or property

Your only option is to use `Marshal.SizeOf`.

Comment: I tried unsafe with sizeof but It does not compile.

Comment: The error you get will tell you that you have to compile with the /unsafe parameter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0.aspx

Comment: I assume you're getting "Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('T')". In that case, [the documentation for that error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2estayf.aspx) shows that you just can't use `sizeof` with any reference type, which T may be.

Comment: All I want is that this works with types like float, int, double, byte, etc, i.e. just simple types.  It seems to me that having to use Marshal, or set unsave flags should not have to be necessary.  Is it not possible to indicate somehow that this is not a managed type?

Comment: No. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspxhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) says "the compiler only knows that T is a reference type, and therefore must use the default operators that are valid for all reference types".

Comment: But if you are only going to be using simple types, then use `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))` as it won't give you any different results than `sizeof` for primitive types.

Comment: You can use `where T: struct` to constrain T to being a value type. But that does not allow you to use `sizeof`.